# dynamically switch scroll physics form never scroll to scroll

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll

The title might not be totally accurate but forgive me I don't really know what to write. I am trying to create an effect where a noScroll phyicas `Listview` that is nested with other elements in a `SingleChildScrollView`, would need to change to a scrollable physics when it reaches the top of the `SingleChildScrollView` (thus occupying the whole view) in order to utilize the lazy loading of items.

I must say I ma trying to avoid rebuilding the nested `Listview` because of that cost and especially the cost of building it with the NeverScrolling physics since that would stall the main UI thread until all items are built.

The necessity of using the NeverScrolling physics in the first place it to allow the `SingleChildScrollView` to properly scroll (if the list view is set to normal scrolling, the `SingleChildScrollView` will not be able to scroll if the gesture is coming from the nested `Listview`)

My code looks like this :

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Material(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ItemListDevider(),
                        Container(
                          height: 120,
                          child: Container(height:120)
                        ),
                        ItemListDevider(),
                        Flexible(
                          fit: FlexFit.loose,
                          child: THeWidgetHoldingTheListView(album),
                        )

                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

```dart
// the build method of the THeWidgetHoldingTheListView widget would return this :
 Container(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Flexible(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        controller: controller,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemExtent: FixedItemExtent,
                        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: FixedItemCount,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return MyCard()
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              MyScrollbar(
                controller: controller,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

*Note: * I had the idea of creating a custom ScrollPhysics that starts as a NeverScrollPhysics and the switches on a certain scroll offset but that wouldn't change the fact that I have to load the entire list as a Neverscroll and thus stalling the main UI thread.

Is there a way to get around this change of scroll physics, if not how can I implement it without compromising on performance like mentioned above.

Comment: Perhaps this answer might help you?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56291223/flutter-how-to-avoid-listview-to-scroll-or-change-its-physics-dynamically

Comment: you have to use `CustomScrollView` and forget about those workarounds with scroll physics

Comment: @WilliamTerrill that actually is something I want to avoid since I have a huge potential list to rebuild and that costs.

Comment: @pskink I am trying to use it but I don't think it will solve my problem differently than a standard list view with dynamic extent would

Comment: it will - for example if your list has 1000 items but only 5 are visible your builder will be called 5-10 times maybe - in your current solution it will be called 1000 times

Comment: @pskink I implemented it with some more widgets like persistent header one and got a fantastic result, thank you

Comment: sure, your welcome, if you used persistent header  you could  try `SliverTransformer` too: https://gist.github.com/pskink/d9775e4dc8bbc5586070229760106031

Comment: @KakiMasterOfTime can you please share your result that worked out well for you?